# Solve the given DE by using a substitution: $ydx + (1+ye^x)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble understanding how to use the substitution method. In the problem above, I have tried using $u=x$ once I've isolated $\frac {dy}{dx}$ but that doesn't work because when I then try to use $e^{-x}$ as the integrating factor I can't get $Mu = Nx$...Thoroughly confused here. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about $u = e^{-x}/y^2$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: try an integrating factor $u(x,y) = e^{-x} f(y)$ and solve for $f(y)$ using the condition $\partial_y (u M) = \partial_x (u N) $. Can you show that $f = c/y^2$, for any nonzero constant $c$?

Comment: Wait but I used $u=x$ as my substitution...Do you mean an integrating factor of $v(u,y)$?

Comment: Yes, and you have also seen than that is not going to work. That's because the integrating factor must have another form - the one I propose to you turns out to work!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Considering the equation $$y +(1+y\,e^x)\,y'=0$$ make a first change of variable $y\,e^x=z$ to get rid of the most unpleasant term;  so $y=z\, e^{-x}$, $y'=e^{-x} \left(z'-z\right)$. Now, rewrite the initial equation and simplify; you should arrive to $$(z+1)\, z'-z^2=0$$ which is now separable.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Claude, could you just elaborate a bit on the step to find $y'$? So I'm deriving $z$ with respect to $x$, but where does the $-z$ come from?